# Is there a shorthand form of the match in Rust?

Tags: rust

Many function calls in Rust return the type `std::result::Result` which is an enum. There are advantages of having such a return type, but writing a matcher looks to be tedious for a small task.

For example, I was trying to find the time a certain portion of my code takes. I tried `SystemTime::now()` coupled with `duration()`:

```
let now = SystemTime::now();

let result = cvar
    .wait_timeout(started, Duration::from_millis(20000))
    .unwrap();
started = result.0;
if *started == false {
    *started = true;
}
println!("Thread 1 :: Exiting...after {:?}s ", now.elapsed().unwrap());
```

This gives me an output in the shape of

```
Thread 1 :: Exiting...after Duration { secs: 6, nanos: 999860814 }s
```

I am aware that I can get the desired result using a match in a similar manner to this as in the [docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/time/struct.SystemTime.html):

```
match now.elapsed() {
    Ok(elapsed) => {
        println!("{}", elapsed.as_secs());
    }
    Err(e) => {
        println!("Error: {:?}", e);
    }
}
```

This would be a few extra lines which do not really contribute to the application logic.

Is there no shorthand for carrying out such a match operation?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unwrap or continue in a loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49785136/unwrap-or-continue-in-a-loop)

Comment: One way could be `now.elapsed().and_then(|x| {
        println!("Thread 1 :: Exiting...after {:?}s ", x);
        Ok(x)
    });`

Comment: Are you searching for something like https://blog.rust-lang.org/2016/11/10/Rust-1.13.html#the--operator ?

Comment: Oh that's a nice construct @hellow .But perhaps it isn't working in my case complaining - `cannot use the `?` operator in a function that returns '()'`.

Comment: you have to return a result ;) see the example in the blog update.
also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42917566/what-is-this-question-mark-operator-about and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40545332/is-the-question-mark-operator-equivalent-to-the-try-macro

Comment: ok I see. Ultimately the error has to be propagated anyhow which demands the return type to be `Result` anyhow.