# Is there a shorthand for evaluating whether a refutable pattern matches?

Tags: rust, pattern-matching

As far as I can tell, refutable patterns can only be tested in `match`, `if let`, and `while let` expressions. To illustrate what I would like to do, consider the use of the `=>` syntax from the match statement in the following context:

```rust
let val = get_optional_value();
if val => Some(inner) {
    do_something(inner);
}
```

I could use an `if let` statement, but a more useful context would be in short closures:

```rust
get_optional_value()
    .filter(|iv| iv => InnerVariant::VariantA)
    .and_then(/* ... */)
```

As far as I can tell, the only solution to achieving this using pattern matching would be:

```rust
get_optional_value()
    .filter(|iv| {
        if let InnerVariant::VariantA = iv {
            true
        } else {
            false
        }
    })
    .and_then(/* ... */)
```

There is a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50523267/is-there-a-shorthand-form-of-the-match-in-rust) that did not get answered but the comments do point to the use of the `?` operator that solves a related corner case for `std::result::Result`.

Comment: I don't really see usecase in your example. what would you do in `and_then` ? cause you need to match again your variant.

Comment: I think there are use cases here but the `and_then` in this example was more to illustrate that if you have chain of methods that take closures this would become very verbose.

Comment: It's hard to answer multiple questions made in one post. Please separate them into multiple questions so that we can help you better and so that your questions will help others in the future that have one of the same questions as you! I've deleted the unrelated question.

Comment: Yes, I was thinking about removing that bit and putting it in its own question... thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Rust 1.42 added the [`matches!`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.matches.html) macro. `matches!(X, Y)` returns a boolean indicating whether expression `X` matches the pattern `Y`.

In your case, it could be used like this:

```rust
get_optional_value()
    .filter(|iv| matches!(iv, InnerVariant::VariantA))
    .and_then(/* ... */)
```

This does not let you bind new names, you can only access the "inner" data in an optional `if` guard.

Comment: I guess you mean: `.filter(|iv| matches!(iv, InnerVariant::VariantA))` right?

Comment: Yes, a copy-paste mistake :)