# How do I ignore an error returned from a Rust function and proceed regardless?

Tags: rust

When it is known that some piece of code might throw an error, we make use of `try/catch` blocks to ignore such errors and proceed. This is done when the error is not that important but maybe we only want to log it:

```java
try{
    int i = 1/0;
} catch( ArithmeticException e){
    System.out.println("Encountered an error but would proceed.");
} 
x = y;
```

Such a construct in Java would continue on to execute `x = y;`.

Can I make use of `match` to do this or any other construct?

I do see a `try!` macro, but perhaps it would return in case of an error with the return type of the method as `Result`.

I want to use such a construct in a UT to ensure it continues to run even after an error has occurred.

Comment: *perhaps it would return* — I recommend reading [the documentation for functions, macros, and types that you find](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.try.html). A lot of time and effort has gone into them and they cover many basic questions.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the resources @Shepmaster. But I had already gone through them. All the error handling variants appeared to me to be working only in case a Result type is being returned. But I was looking to handle some case very analogous to the try/catch mentioned above. My function returns a value and not a Result or Option type, but may panic which is what I wanted to ignore.

Comment: You can use [catch_unwind](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/panic/fn.catch_unwind.html) but it is not recommended. Docs "It is not recommended to use this function for a general try/catch mechanism. The Result type is more appropriate to use for functions that can fail on a regular basis."

Comment: I think the reason why somebody downvoted your question is, that you should not "throw away" the error. Handle it properly (you may do this with `expect`) or return it, so the caller can handle the error itself.

Comment: Yes thanks @hellow for pointing it out. But its in a UT that I am willing to do this where anyways there are mocking and stuff to get around things. I might even go on to assert in the catch block but do not want to stop the progress of the UT.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

Functions in Rust which can fail return a [`Result`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/):

> `Result<T, E>` is the type used for returning and propagating errors. It is an enum with the variants, `Ok(T)`, representing success and containing a value, and `Err(E)`, representing error and containing an error value.

I highly recommend reading the [Error Handling section](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch09-00-error-handling.html) in the [Rust Book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/):

> Rust has a number of features for handling situations in which something goes wrong

If you want to ignore an error, you have different possibilities:

- Don't use the `Result`:

  ```
    let _ = failing_function();
  ```

  The function will be called, but the result will be ignored. If you omit `let _ =` , you will get a warning. As of Rust 1.59, you can omit the let and just write `_ = failing_function();`.
- Ignore the `Err` variant of `Result` using [`if let`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch06-03-if-let.html) or [`match`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch06-02-match.html):

  ```
    if let Ok(ret) = failing_function() {
        // use the returned value
    }
  ```

  You may also convert the `Result` into [`Option`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html) with [`Result::ok`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html#method.ok):

  ```
    let opt = failing_function().ok();
  ```
- Unwrap the error. This code panics if an error occurred though:

  ```
    let ret = failing_function().unwrap();
    // or
    let ret = failing_function().expect("A panic message to be displayed");
  ```

`try!()` unwraps a result and early returns the function, if an error occurred. However, you should use `?` instead of `try!` as [this is deprecated](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/62672).

---

See also:

- [What is this question mark operator about?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42917566/what-is-this-question-mark-operator-about)
- [Is the question mark operator ? equivalent to the try! macro?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40545332/is-the-question-mark-operator-equivalent-to-the-try-macro)
- [How to do error handling in Rust and what are the common pitfalls?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30505639/how-to-do-error-handling-in-rust-and-what-are-the-common-pitfalls)

Comment: Calling `Result::ok` just turns it into an `Option`. Then you basically have the same story as in `Result`

Comment: Nope, because rustc _does_ complain about an unused Result<T, \_> but it _doesn't_ complain about an unused Option<T>

Comment: Not sure if there's a more idiomatic way to tell the compiler "I intentionally ignored that result"

Comment: It's expressive to type `let _`. It gives a hint to the compiler, that you don't use the value and other readers (or youself at a later point) will see that, too.

Comment: You can also use `unwrap_or` or `unwrap_or_default`. Example: `std::fs::remove_file(file).unwrap_or_default();` to delete a file, ignoring any errors.

Comment: How could you log an error (i.e., with `println!`) and proceed, as the OP originally asked?   I've tried `.or_else` with no luck.

Comment: @workerjoe `.or_else` requires a return value. You may either use `if let Ok(...) = result { ... } else { println!(...) }` or a `match result { ... }` statement.

Comment: As someone stumbling here with the same question, I believe `if let Ok(ret) = failing_function()` was the answer being searched for. I basically just didn't want to do `match failing_function() { Err(_) => {}, Ok(ret) => { ... }`

Comment: As of Rust 1.59, you can omit the `let` and just write `_ = failing_function();` in order to ignore the result of `failing_function()`. See https://twitter.com/davidtolnay/status/1564729670779604993, https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/master/RELEASES.md#version-1590-2022-02-24 and https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/79016

Comment: Thanks, @JeroenWiertPluimers, I added this to the answer.